# Searching for invoices with Paypal-PHP-SDK fails

Tags: search, invoice, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm unable to search for invoices based on the invoice status. I have tried the following:

```
        //$searchString = '[{
        //                  "status" : "SENT",
        //                  "page" : 0,
        //                  "page_size" : 0,
        //                  "total_count_required" : true
        //                 }]';
```

This above search string returns http response 500.

```
        $searchString = '{
                          "status" : "SENT",
                          "page" : 0,
                          "page_size" : 0,
                          "total_count_required" : "true"
                         }';
```

This above search string returns "{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","message":"Invalid request - see details.","debug_id":"e8b3b40ca05f4","details":[{"field":"status","issue":"Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token at line:1, column:2"}]}".

```
        //$searchString = '{
        //                  "page" : 0,
        //                  "page_size" : 0,
        //                  "total_count_required" : true
        //                 }';
```

The above search string returns all invoices.

```
        $search = new Search($searchString);

        $invoices = Invoice::search($search, $apiContext);
```

Has anyone been able to search based on invocie status?

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue myself. Its probably a little late for @Jim but the answer was to put the stats in an array. This way you can query multiple status.

```
"status" : ["SENT"],
```

or for mulitiple

```
"status" : ["SENT", "PAID"],
```

Hope this helps someone